# Ruby Active Record Relational

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

Still a newbie here, but I still couldn't get the logic right.

Currently, I have:

1. User has many products.
2. Product has 1 user with a price attribute.

I am trying to add on:

1. User can offer 1 price on a product sold by another user. User can offer price on multiple products.
2. A Product can have many offered price by multiple users.

I have currently come out with:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :products
 has_many :offered_prices
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :offered_prices
end
```

This is what I have done so far. It still doesn't seem quite right as I am rather confused at the same time. Your help is very much appreciated! :)

Comment: You need a has_many :through assocation. Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define three models:

```
User | OfferedPrice | Product
```

The association amongst them will be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :offered_prices, through: :products
end

class OfferedPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product

  # To make sure a user can offer price once for against a product
  validates_uniqueness_of :price, scope: [:user, :product]
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offered_prices
  has_many :user, through: :offered_prices
end
```